# Are there examples of Googie architecture outside the U.S.?

Tags: usa, sightseeing, architecture, locate-this

Falling in perhaps both the genres of "futurist" and "kitsch", [Googie architecture](http://paleofuture.gizmodo.com/googie-architecture-of-the-space-age-512620908) is a classification for buildings which take on certain exaggerated, stylized characteristics, such as:

> cantilevered structures, acute angles, illuminated plastic paneling, freeform boomerang and artist's palette shapes and cutouts, and tailfins on buildings.

[image](source for quote and [photo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googie_architecture#/media/File:Elm_Road_Drive-In_Theatre-2.jpg): Wikipedia).

Wikipedia also does a great job of elaborating on where in the U.S. these features are common (Las Vegas, Miami, Southern California); however, no examples of where else in the world this kind of architecture could be found.

Is it exclusive to the U.S.? If not, where else should I travel to see more of it? Perhaps Russia has some places due to the style's connection to the Space Race?

Comment: Probably the new extension to the Tate Modern might qualify.  It will be finished soon.  The connection to travel, however, is tenuous.  I'm asking the higher ups to make a ruling on your question as off topic or not.

Comment: It certainly exists in Canada.  Does that count as outside US? ;-)

Comment: If anyone needs examples, watch the original "The Jetson's" cartoons. Also the original Disneyland's Tomorrowland was originally done in the Googie style.

Comment: @JoErNanO - That makes sense to me. I essentially want to know where I can go see these things internationally, if they exist.

Comment: Concerning the photo in the question, it seems questionable whether a street sign is a good example for *architecture*, unless you are specifically looking for signs rather than buildings.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to take a look at Oscar Niemeyer's buildings in Brasília, Brazil, such as:

The National Cathedral:

[image]

The Palacio do Planalto:

[image]

The National Congress:

[image]

I don't know if the exact term "Googie" was ever applied to Niemeyer's work, but it's definitely of the same vintage and has a space-age feel to it.